# Storing data from for each loop for output to HTML table

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to figure out how to create an object in Azure Logic Apps that I can append to, and ultimately output that to an HTML table.  I use the term 'object', but I'm not sure what it's called in Logic Apps.

I have 4 variables I want to append to the 'object' whenever an if statement is true: skuPartNumber, TrueTotalLicense, ActiveLicense, and Percentage.  Once the for each loop is complete, I want to output the contents of that object as an HTML table I can put in an email.  What do I need to use to store the values of those variables that can be appended to?

Answer (score 0):

The word you're looking for is `Array`.  It can hold multiple values that you can then loop through later or create your HTML table.

So firstly, you need to initialise an `Array` variable up front.

[image: Array Variable]

Then within your loop, you should use the `Append to array variable` action to write a new object to the array.

[image: Append]

Obviously, just replace my placeholder values with your own from within your loop ...

```
{
  "skuPartNumber': "something",
  "TrueTotalLicense": "something",
  "ActiveLicense": "something",
  "Percentage": 0.32
}
```

#### Important Point

Variables are globally scoped, meaning, if you update them in a loop and that loop does not run sequentially (i.e. Concurrency Control is turned off or is greater than 1 degree of parallelism ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-loops?tabs=consumption#for-each-run-sequentially) then you will have problems.

Now having said that, you **don't** have that issue with the `Append to array variable` operation.  It's just something to note if you start using variables in other ways.